# Is variation in price-dividend ratios that is attributable to excess returns due to variation in returns or variation in risk free rates?

Tags: volatility, equities, interest-rates, returns, asset-returns

Cochrane and Fama show that "all variation in price-dividend ratios corresponds to changes in expected excess returns -risk premiums- and none corresponds to news about future dividend growth". Is this variation in excess returns due to variation in returns or variation in risk free rates?